# Building a Data Sorting program c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to build a data sorting program for work.

I have a bunch of data files that I need to filter/combine the duplicates then go through and modify the filtered data.

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8RJt.png)

so these are the raw data files that contain a bunch of variables (ID;Length;Priority;etc;etc;etc;ItemCode;Quanity;CompletedItem)

This is the end result I'm aiming for.
[After filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vqfY.png)

so all the duplicates are combined and their quantities are added together

here's a simplified version of the data files before sorting.
[-Image-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djz2E.png)

and after which might help clear things up so it's not just a wall of numbers
[-Image-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPZ8P.png)

The last step I'm looking at doing is going through a holder full of raw data files sorting and fixing them up.

I'm a fairly new programmer so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code to do that

```
List<Data> data = new List<Data>()
            {
                new Data(){ID="1",ItemCode="code1" },
                new Data(){ID="3",ItemCode="code3" },
                new Data(){ID="4",ItemCode="code4" },
                new Data(){ID="2",ItemCode="code2" },
                new Data(){ID="1",ItemCode="code1" },
                new Data(){ID="1",ItemCode="code1" },
                new Data(){ID="2",ItemCode="code2" },
                
            };
            var n = data.OrderBy(x => x.ItemCode).ThenBy(x => x.ID).GroupBy(x=>x.ItemCode, x=>x.ID)
                .ToList();
```